# Does A* work with negative weights as long that the heuristic is admissible?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

This seems *true* but I can't find anyone on the internet saying it is, so I'd like to make sure. Please tell me if you agree and if so, why. Ideally a link to a paper, or, if you disagree, a counterexample.

Let `G` be a directed graph with some negative edges. We want to run A* on `G`.

First off, if `G` has negative cycles reachable from the source and reaching the goal, there is no admissible heuristic, as it's impossible to underestimate the cost of reaching the goal because it's `-∞`.

If there are no such cycles however, there may be some admissible heuristic. In particular, the sum of all negative edges will always underestimate the cost of reaching the goal.

I'm under the impression that in this case, A* may work just fine.

P.S. I could run Bellman-Ford on the graph, detect negative cycles, and if there are none, reweigh to get rid of negative edges. But, if I *know* there are no negative cycles, I can just skip that and run A*.

---

This is trivially wrong. The cost of a vertex is the sum of the heuristic and the path built so far... while the heuristic underestimates the cost to reach the goal, the sum of the heuristic and the path taken so far may not. Maxima culpa.

It seems that sorting the open set with a function that underestimates the cost to reach the goal, while going through a given vertex may work though... if one uses `<sum of negative edges in the graph>` as such a function, it looks like it degenerates into a graph traversal.

Comment: Might be also good to ask on the cstheory.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the example with 3 nodes and 3 weights:

```
1 2 -10
1 3 -3
3 2 -8
```

From 1 to 2 there is path with weight -10. So you get this first and establish it as the minimal path to 2. However there is path (1-3-2) which is smaller than the first one.

Comment: Argh, yes, if my heuristic is a constant I'm basically getting Dijkstra all over again... Should have seen that. I'm working with a different heuristic in a specific class of graph where this works, and I got carried on thinking it was more general.

Comment: There's no PM here, but I'd like your input on my edit... if instead of using  Path_Cost_top[a] + Heuristic[a,goal] one uses Heuristic[source,a] + Heuristic[source,goal], you end up with a graph traversal that expand nodes less likely to be later found to have a lower cost.

Comment: I believe this is wrong, as Nitesh described below.

Comment: A* tree search will work with negative heuristic but A* graph search might not. A* graph search can even be broken by a positive admissible 
heuristic. So there's that.

Comment: @NiteshBharadwaj What do you mean? If the weights of the graph are negative?

Comment: @Ant, I meant negative heuristic. In this case, since we have negative edge weights, admissible heuristic has to be negative at places. In addition, we need to implement it using a tree search paradigm instead of graph search. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680180/graph-search-vs-tree-search

Comment: This seems to be wrong. If we assume 2 is the goal state and uses `h(2) = 0`, which it should have, then A* will add it to the open frontier with `f(2) = -10` but expand the path 1-3 first, as `h(3) <= -8` (admissibility) thus `f(3) <= -11`.
Then it can (e.g.) update `f(2)` to `<= -11` and never take the 1-2 path.

(Note that A* terminates once the goal state is picked from the open frontier and therefore has the lowest `f` value.)

Comment: @h4nek and why would that result be wrong? If you have negative weights it means you have rewards not costs, so you do want to go through the longer path that gives you -11 no?

Answer (score 5):

In the example given by top rated answer:
(2,-10) goes into priority queue. Agreed. 
So does (3,x) where x<=-11 as heuristic is admissible.
Now (3,x) gets popped as x<-10 and we get to the correct solution.

I can't put this as a comment as I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

> This is trivially wrong. The cost of a vertex is the sum of the
>   heuristic and the path built so far... while the heuristic
>   underestimates the cost to reach the goal, the sum of the heuristic
>   and the path taken so far may not.

A* will never expand a node such that the sum of the heuristic and the path taken so far (f-value) is greater than the optimal path length. This is because, along the optimal path, there is always one node with f-value less than or equal to the optimal cost.

Thus, even with negative-weight edges, A* will find the optimal path if such a path exists, as long as there are finite number of edges with f-value less than the optimal cost.

Comment: To add to the quoted text (in other words): if the heuristic underestimates the cost to reach the goal, then surely the path taken so far plus the heuristic will underestimate the cost of the minimal path (that uses the current node).