# Suboptimal solution given by A* search

Tags: search, artificial-intelligence, heuristics

I don't understand how the following graph gives a suboptimal solution with A* search.

[image]

The graph above was given as an example where A* search gives a suboptimal solution, i.e the heuristic is admissible but not consistent. Each node has a heuristic value corresponding to it and the weight of traversing a node is given. I don't understand how A* search will expand the nodes.

Comment: Only A* with "graph search" will return a suboptimal solution. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680180/graph-search-vs-tree-search/15281447#15281447.

Comment: Imho the pseudoimplementation of the "A* graph" is a really bad one  but it can be the only reason for a subopt solution.

Answer (score 6):

The heuristic h(n) is not consistent.

Let me first define when a heuristic function is said to be consistent.

```
h(n) is consistent if  
– for every node n
– for every successor n' due to legal action a 
– h(n) <= c(n,a,n') + h(n')
```

Here clearly 'A' is a successor to node 'B'
but `h(B) > h(A) + c(A,a,B)`

Therefore the heuristic function is not consistent/monotone, and so A* need not give an optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I don't see how A* could return a sub-optimal solution with the given heuristic.
This is for a simple reason: the given heuristic is admissible (and even monotone/consistent).

```
h(s) <= h*(s) for each s in the graph
```

You can check this yourself comparing the h value in each node to the cost of shortest path to g.

Given the optimality property of A* I don't see how it could return a sub-optimal solution, which should be `S -> A -> G` of course.

The only way it could return a suboptimal solution is if it would stop once an action from a node in the frontier leading to the goal is found (so to have a path to the goal), **but this would not be A***.

Comment: The heuristic is not monotone. It decreases from B to A.

Comment: True, not only there. Still is admissible and should guarantee optimality.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused today. :)

Comment: Your comment was actually relevant. The heuristic is not consistent.

Comment: But it is possible to have a situation where A* search gives a suboptimal solution if the heuristic is admissible but not consistent right? Could you provide me with some example of that?

Comment: Afaik it is NOT possible: admissibility leads to optimality, both in terms of cost of the solution and of nodes expanded.

Comment: @Crackej If the heuristic is not monotone, then you need to reopen nodes, as you can later encounter them on a cheaper path.

Comment: Ofc, this is why I said that the pseudocode implementation of the link was a bad one ;)

Answer (score 0):

In graph search, we don't expand the already discovered nodes.

f(node) = cost to node from that path + h(node)

At first step:

```
fringe = {S} - explored = {}
```

S is discarded from the fringe and A and B are added.

```
fringe = {A, B} - explored = {S}
```

Then f(A) = 5 and f(B) = 7. So we discard A from the fringe and add G.

```
fringe = {G, B} - explored = {S, A}
```

Then f(G) = 8 and f(B) = 7 so we discard B from the fringe but don't add A since we already explored it.

```
fringe = {G} - explored = {S, A, B}
```

Finally we have only G left in the fringe So we discard G from the fringe and we have reached our goal.

The path would be S->A->G.
If this was a tree search problem, then we would find the answer S->B->A->G since we would reconsider the A node.